# Error while encrypting string in staticLibrary

Tags: ios, ios5, encryption, ios4, ios-simulator

In my application I am using encryption and decryption.

Before entering the string in to local database, I am encrypting that and after fetching the data from database I am decrypting it and using in my application.
It is working fine. I have used encryption/decryption from
[link below](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/20/encrypting-decrypting-base64-encode-decode-in-iphone-objective-c/)

**At the time of Encrypting:**

```
    NSString *myKey=@"any string more than 8 char";

    NSData *data ; 
    NSData *encryptedData; 
    NSString *encryptPassword,*encryptPasscode;

    // 1) Encrypt

    data = [password dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    encryptedData = [data AESEncryptWithPassphrase:myKey];

    // 2) Encode Base 64

    [Base64 initialize];
    encryptPassword = [Base64 encode:encryptedData];
```

**At the time of Decrypting :**

```
    NSData *decryptedData;
    NSData  *b64DecData;

    field1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectPasscodeStatement, 0);
    NSString *fieldStr1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: field1];

     // 3) Decode Base 64

      b64DecData = [Base64 decode:fieldStr1];

     // 4) Decrypt

       decryptedData = [b64DecData AESDecryptWithPassphrase:myKey];

       retrivedPasscode = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

But I have made staticLibrary of that same project. I am using that staticLibrary in another project. When I run that project, at the time of encrypting it gave me error below

> **-[NSConcreteMutableData AESEncryptWithPassphrase:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a3fe40**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make change in the Build Settings of the project which will link the static library with the main project.
Follow these steps:

1)Click on Build Settings tab.

2)Search for "Other Linker Flags".

3)Add '-all_load' flag to it.

4)Build and run the project.

It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the category header file:

```
#import "NSData-AES.h"
```

I believe there is the `AESDecryptWithPassphrase` method defined. Without that the app does not know about the method.

Just to clarify - you have to import the category header file to every file where you want to use the capabilities added by that category.

Comment: -> yes, I have included #import "NSData-AES.h" in both in staticLibrary and in current project also.

I don't know how it is calling to [NSConcreteMutableData AESEncryptWithPassphrase:] function